# Best practices to sync the client side vuex state to the server side state?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, server-side-rendering

I have cloned [vue-hackernews-2.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0), a Vue.js app with SSR and vuex.

This app [listens on port 8080](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/blob/98399b55c6f1da4197840ba76189795b3e95be0f/server.js#L120), while my api server listens on 3000 in my local dev environment.I am trying to implement user authentication in it, using jwt.

when the client recieves the token from api server,the client state updates with the token, But **How do I make the server side state aware that the user is logged in** ?

In general, how to sync client side and server side state?

An ugly hack I thought of is that when the user logs in with correct credentials, the api server should open a socket connection with the **8080** server and trigger a state update on server side? Is it an acceptable/scalable solution? 
What are the best practices regarding this?

**MORE DETAILS..**
(a) in router I implemented the navigation guard :

```
      ....
      if (router.app.$store.getters.isLoggedIn)  next()
      else  next('/login')
      ...
```

Now on login in my Login page, I post an action to my api server (NOT the vue server on port 8080) , and store the token in client side state. 
But when I reload the logged in dashboard page, it can't find the token on server side state, the function `isLoggedIn` above returns false,  and it tries to render the login page **please see the code above**, the client side DOM thus doesn't match the server rendered page, and client tries to re-render the DOM on client side.

Answer (score 1):

Well,
you wrote you're using jwt.

So the server doesn't need to know if the user is logged in.

As long as the client provides this jwt on every request (header, cookie, (body)), the server can authorize these requests.

To proper handle [jwt](https://jwt.io/), you could use the [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) package:

```
const JWT = require('jsonwebtoken')
```

Issuing a token:

```
const token = JWT.sign({
    userId: user.id,
    moreData: undefined,
  },
   'somRandomLongPrivateKey123', // protect it, env var?
  {
    expiresIn: '2d',
  })
```

Middleware to validate the token:

```
module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {
try {
  const payload = JWT.verify(token, 'yourprivatekey') 
  req.user = User.find(payload.userId) 

  next()

} catch(e) {
  return res.status(401).send('no valid token')  
}
```

Comment: the question was: In general, how to sync client side and server side state?

where should I verify and generate the above JWT on SSR server or backend server? In fact the question is bit more complex. Please try going in more details. Thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: I have found the solution though. I can write a detailed answer if someone needs  it and facing the same odd problem I WAS facing.. :)

Comment: @RameshPareek it is always a good idea to post a detailed answer if you have one - I would like to see it.

Comment: @Brent, yes I do have, Actually it took me one long week to achieve this and I can't forget that week during my lifetime, however I could understand some of the inner engineering of how vue js works. People say vuejs docs are good but I think this is mentioned nowhere in docs. How do you manage a user's logged in state while you are rendering on server side. I would soon post a good article about this on medium.